# Making a base class method that instantiates a new subclass object depending on the subclass that called the method

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I've searched and searched, but to be honest, I don't really know what to look for. 
I have this abstract base class called Item, and I will have a lot of subclasses that all will need to use the method `Split(double amount)` in the base class. I want that method to somehow know what subclass called it and be able to instantiate a new object of that type.
This is for a weird game of mine, but I need this specific method to split a stack of items into two...

!!! The base class is called `Item`, even though the subclasses will represent item-types AND a quantity of that itemtype, sort of like a stack in some games... !!!

This is what I've got so far:

```
public abstract class Item
{
    public double Quantity { get; private set; }

    public Item()
    {
        Quantity = 1;
    }

    public Item(double quantity)
    {
        Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public bool Merge(Item item)
    {
        if (item.GetType() == GetType())
        {
            Quantity += item.Quantity;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Item Split(double amount, Type häst)
    {
        Quantity -= amount;
        //Here I'd like to do something like "new the-type-that-called-this-method()" 
    }
}
```

I know that I could use an abstract method in the base class, and override it in every subclass, but then I'd have to re-write basically the exact same code I don't know how many times... I guess this is what I'll be doing though if I can't find a better way...

BTW, if you have any other suggestions or you think that my way of organizing this is stupid, then don't hesistate to tell me, I've never done anything like this and I tend to overcomplicate simple things and simply make it harder for myself for some reason...

Better explanation???
For example, if I've got a "stack" of 200 `IronOre` (let's say `IronOre : Item`, and this instance is stored in `myIronPile`) then I want to take 70 `IronOre` and put that in a new "stack". Therefore I want to call `myOtherIronPile = myIronPile.Split(70)`. This will remove 70 from `myIronPile` and put that into a new `IronOre` instance stored in `myOtherIronPile`.

Any help is greatly apprieciated! Thanks! :D

Comment: As i understood maybe keyword is will help

Answer (score 0):

To make an object of a given type you can use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___) (from `System.Reflection` namespace):

```
public Item Split(double amount)
{
    Quantity -= amount;
    return Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(), new object[] { amount }) as Item;
}
```

`GetType` is a virtual call which returns the "real" type of the object, in the most derived form.

---

A better way would be to make a generic method as you operate on the derived type instead of the base class `Item`:

```
public static T Split<T>(T item, double amount) where T: Item
{
    item.Quantity -= amount;
    return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { amount }) as T;
}
```

Then you use it like that:

```
var myIronPile = new IronOre(200);
var myOtherIronPile = Item.Split(myIronPile, 70);
```

But be careful with using these operations on an `Item` variable as this wouldn't work:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
items.Add(new IronOre(200));
var myOtherPile = Item.Split(items[0], 70); // call to Item.Split<Item>(...) !
```

This would make `Activator.CreateInstance` throw an exception as the type it would want to instantiate is abstract.

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
items.Add(new IronOre(200));

var myOtherPile = Item.Split(items[0] as IronOre, 70); // works

IronOre item = items[0] as IronOre;
myOtherPile = Item.Split(item, 70); // also works
```

Other solution is to just use the runtime type with `GetType` which incurs a probably unnoticable performance penalty (`typeof` is a compile-time construct):

```
public static T Split<T>(T item, double amount) where T: Item
{
    item.Quantity -= amount;
    return Activator.CreateInstance(item.GetType(), new object[] { amount }) as T;
}
```

One problem persists, though:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
items.Add(new IronOre(200));

var myOtherPile = Item.Split(items[0], 70); // myOtherPile is of type Item

IronOre myOtherPile = Item.Split(items[0], 70); // error, cast needed
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

First off, `Split` seems to be a bad name for your method. When I see your method’s name the first thing that comes to mind on what it does is: given an item, it splits it in two new ones. But that is not what it does, it actually mutates the given item and extracts part of it into a new one.

Hmmm... isn’t `Extract` a better name?

```
public Item Extract(double amount)
```

Ok, now when I see this method, my first impression actually matches what it really does.

We can also give it a twist using generics to make it as strongly typed as possible and if we make it static method we can also leverage type inference to help us out (we’ll modify the name slightly to make it more consistent with it being static):

```
 public static T ExtractFrom<T>(T item, double amount)
    where T: Item
 {
     item.Quantity -= amount;
     return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(
         item.GetType(), new object[] { amount });
 }
```

You could even consider implementing this as an extension method although I try to avoid mutating extension methods if possible.

Note that I’m using the runtime type of `item` and not `typeof(T)`. This is simply due to the fact that it’s quite possible that type inference might resolve to `Item` and you would get a runtime error as you can’t directly instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: Mutating extension method wouldn't even be possible in this case as `Quantity` has a private setter.

Comment: @JakubDąbek true, missed that detail, extension methods is not an option, which is good as I stated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `Item` class take a type-parameter for the concrete `Item` type it represents, kind of like a *self-type*. This will also help with the `Merge` method and you can have a factory `Create` method to make creation easier:

```
public abstract class Item<T> where T : Item<T>, new() {
  public double Quantity { get; private set; }
  public static T Create(double quantity) {
    return new T { Quantity = quantity };
  }
  public void Merge(T item) {
    Quantity += item.Quantity;
  }
  public T Split(double amount) {
    Quantity -= amount;
    return Create(amount);
  }
}
```

Subclasses *must* provide themselves as type parameters and must also have a parameterless constructor (the implicit one is fine):

```
public class IronOre : Item<IronOre> { }
```

Also note that this self-type parameter is by convention only, *you* are the one who makes sure the subclasses behave.

Sample usage based on your example:

```
var myIronPile = IronOre.Create(200);
...
var myOtherIronPile = myIronPile.Split(70);
```

More info about this pattern and its pitfalls [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/).